# Mercurial Workflow Step by Step to Send Changes Selectively to Another Repository

Tags: svn, mercurial

I want to use Mercurial for development on my dev box (standalone). I read that Mercurial is better than Subversion for standalone system in StackOverflow answers.

My flow is this:

- I want to work on Wordpress and there I want to have two copy of code.
- Both copy will be same at first but I will work on say, 1st copy.
- After the changes to various files, I want to selectively copy/commit changes to 2nd codebase
- From 2nd codebase, I want to pick changed files so that I can put those files on shard hosting server.

I tried to read from Documentation but I could not find how to do this. I learnt how to change in one copy, commit the change, update to 2nd copy, etc. But selectively I could not do those. I can use TortoiseHG, if answer given for that. I have tried using command line as TortoiseHG has so many options to explore.

Also, How to name different codebase?

Comment: Why do you have to different copies/versions of the code?

Comment: So that I can send selected files to 2nd codebase and from there I list files to upload. Not files I have changed in 1st codebase may needed to send to live!

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial has the commands `import` and `export` which allow you to import and export individual changesets.

But my feeling is that this will be brittle in your case.

A better approach is usually to to create two branches. One branch contains all the files. Name it `work` or use the already existing `default`.

The second branch should be called `publish`.

Use [cherry picking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670076/how-do-i-cherry-pick-a-single-revision-in-mercurial) to copy individual changes from the `work` branch into the `publish` branch.

Using commands like `hg log`, you can determine later which files have changed recently which tells you which ones you have to upload to your server).

That said, it still feels like you're not telling us all the details that we need to know to help you.

Comment: +1. My selected files means that some files can have uncooked recipes. So, I want to see in diff and decide. This is the main concern.

Comment: It may happen that I send files I wish to upload to publish branch but don't do that time itself. Then changelog of publish branch will tell me any time what to upload.

Comment: In my own work, I have meta data per file which tells me in which state it is. That means all my files are in one place and one repository and one branch. A tool will then collect all changed files (changelog) with a certain state (`PUBLISH`). A secured area for beta readers gets files in `BETA` state. All other states aren't published (even though they could be).

Comment: I could not understand much. Do you do what you said above in Mercurial or something else? How to set meta data Publish etc.

Comment: I have my own custom tools. The meta data is stored in a couple of XML documents in the project. Mercurial just manages the files.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of VCS systems (regardless of whether it's Hg or SVN or whatever) is that **you'll never need more than one copy of a codebase**! The feature of *branching* is made for this. So, don't shoot yourself in the foot by messing around with different copies.
You can check out different branches to different disk locations, if you absolutely must - but I strongly advise you to maintain all of your code in one single VCS repository!